# Laravel 5.4 with PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

Good Afternoon:

I am trying to connect Laravel 5.4 with PostgreSQL 9.5. When I try to apply php artisan migrate I have the follow error:

[image]

I modified the php.ini and uncomment the extensions pdo_pgsql and pgsql.

[image]

I changed .env and config/database.php

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432

 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
```

I don't know, what can I do for fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: does `php -m` from the command line return PDO and pdo_pgsql as well?

Comment: No, I don't have pdo_pgsql. I have pdo_mysql and pdo_sqlite. How I can to install it? I modified the php.ini that is not?

Comment: If it's in your webserver phpinfo and not in the command line check if you have a conflicting version of PHP and remove it.

Comment: I am using Mamp, PHP 5.6.28 and Apache. Sorry, this answer is not for your last answer. I am going to check.

Comment: I am using Mamp, PHP 5.6.28, in Laravel "php": ">=5.6.4". However, when I exectute php -v the version is:  PHP 7.0.13. Have I to remove this version?

Comment: If you can find the location where the 5.6 version is installed (maybe /use/local) then you can use the full path to /bin/PHP to run it . It's a pain but could save you a bit of trouble of having to remove one version and link the binaries to the exec path.

Comment: Alternatively if you're using aptitude or similar (brew in macs?) then you can just install pdo_pgsql for the CLI version as well.

Comment: I have windows. Can be because I have Mamp and Xampp and there is some problem with the compatibility? I am going to desinstall Mamp and update xampp and test.

Answer (score 0):

I removed Mamp and updated Xampp to php5.6.30. I installed modules in php.ini and it work correctly now.

Thanks for your help apokryfos